# C++ Sorting huge binary files

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I need to sort huge binary files that won't fit into memory. It's no option to use a sort algorithm and continuously read/write from I/O device. Is there any possibility to use something like a memory mapped file?

Comment: Why is read/writing continously not an option? Do you need random-access?

Comment: Just as a rough idea, you may want to look into what are known as "online algorithms". Basically, the idea is you can sort the data as you receive piece by piece. See for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Utility_in_online_sorting

Comment: Answer to the question as it is currently asked is: yes, there is such possibility. You should ask a better question.

Comment: Have you looked into using a modified `B-Tree` or something similar? That way, you can take data right off of disk instead of memory.

Comment: You'll have a problem sorting data that you cannot read. How are you going to read it if 'you cannot continuously read/write from I/O device'? I'm thinking you _meant to say_ something like: repeatedly read or access the disk non-sequentially :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solved problem, as explained on this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Basically, read in some set amount, sort it, save into a file, and repeat.
Then, read in a smaller amount from each file, sort these, and continue until done.

**UPDATE**:

You may want to look at the java code he uses, it sounds like he solved what you need.

http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2007/5/10/Sorting-really-BIG-files/1194

Answer (score 3):

One strategy is to sort chunks of it with quick sort or some other fast memory sort algorithm and then do a merge sort of these chunks.

Comment: Actually you just have to merge the chunks, a full mergesort would be wasteful.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: If you have many chunks, you really don't want to merge them.  Instead you want to recursively merge the chunks in the same pattern as mergesort.

Answer (score 1):

Here a nice solution with C++11:

https://github.com/alveko/external_sort

And some other options:

- https://github.com/arq5x/kway-mergesort
- https://stxxl.org/
- https://github.com/owaisnm/external-sort
- https://gist.github.com/manangandhi7/98d2cdd12c7800aaea3ecdc41a7755e3

Answer (score -2):

If they won't fit into memory, they won't fit into memory, and that's pretty much that. You can't memory map above your memory limit- a sort algorithm would need all the data at once.

However, you could write a specialized sort algorithm. If you are sorting by byte, for example, you should be able to just loop through the file in chunks, count the occurrence of each byte, and then emit them in order. This could also work for if you're sorting each larger type as long as there are plenty of duplicates to be found.